# how to retrieve 'http header and body' from 'pcap TCPTracker'

Tags: node.js, pcap

I've a requirement where I use [**pcap**](https://github.com/node-pcap/node_pcap) nodejs module to set events and listen incoming and out going traffic on a specific port. pcap uses only interface and basic filters to capture the traffic.

To manage filters to a deeper level I'm using [**http_trace**](https://github.com/mranney/http_trace) to filter based on http method, query parameters etc.
Need to parse the HTTP request and response from pcap so that header and body are accessible as JSON

http_trace seems to be working on only NodeJS v4. And the HTTPSession events used in the http_trace seems to be not working. So I'm left with only the decoded data that contains HTTP header and body as a Buffer type.

```
    var tcp_tracker = new pcap.TCPTracker();

    pcap_session.on("packet", function (raw_packet) {
        var packet = pcap.decode.packet(raw_packet);
        
        // how to convert 'packet' to JSON    
        
        tcp_tracker.track_packet(packet);
    });
```

#### I'm able to get

(when convert the buffer to string and print)

POST /pcap-test?type=cc HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: x.x.x.x:xxxx
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------239200400107608000086018
content-length: 166

----------------------------239200400107608000086018
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

shripad

#### I expect the output somewhat like

{ header: { content-type: "multipart/form-data", Cache-Control: "no-cache" }, body: 'name="name"

shripad' }

separation of header and body is the main goal